# Cookie não é deletado - PHP

Tags: php

Não sei o erro que estou cometendo ao criar uma classe, mas não estou conseguindo deletar o cookie com minha class.

```
public function cookie($name, $value = 'nome', $expire = NULL, $path = '/', $domain = NULL, $secure = FALSE, $httponly = TRUE) {
                setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
                return $this;
        }

public function delete($name){

            unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
            // empty value and expiration one hour before
            setcookie($name, NULL, -1);
            //return var_dump($_COOKIE);
        }

$cs->cookie('meu', 'sd', time()+1800);
$cs->delete('meu');
```

Eu não sei porque mais no meu navegador o cookie não é deletado, oque estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de testar, aqui está o código a funcionar:

```php
function cookie($name, $value = 'nome', $expire = NULL, $path = '/', $domain = NULL, $secure = FALSE, $httponly = TRUE) {
                setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
                //return $this;
        }

function delete($name, $value = 'nome', $expire = NULL, $path = '/', $domain = NULL, $secure = FALSE, $httponly = TRUE) {
            unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
            setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
        }

cookie('omeucookie', 'sd', time()+1800);
delete('omeucookie', 'sd', 1);
```

Para fazer o delete do cookie precisas de lhe mandar tb o seu valor (sd) e a path (/) que definiste anteriormente.

Comment: Ricardo, sinceramente não estou entendendo. O cookie continua aparecendo no Chrome (até mesmo em uma extensão) e no Firefox, mas quando tento buscar o nome e verifico que ele existe, diz que ele não existe. Mas o cookie continua aparecendo.  Quando eu não uso a classe, ele remove o cookie e fica sem nada. O que será que tem de errado?

Comment: Ok, já descobri! Para além do nome do cookie tens de lhe passar também o valor e a path:


`
function delete($name, $value = 'nome', $expire = NULL, $path = '/', $domain = NULL, $secure = FALSE, $httponly = TRUE) {
            unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
            setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
        }
delete('omeucookie', 'sd', 1);
`

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui, e no meu caso é a `path` que está emperrando tudo, quando eu passo ela, ele remove o cookie. Abraços...